# Server to cache HTTP data

Tags: proxy, cache, caching

I'm looking for software for ubuntu where I can place my ubuntu server on my network in such a way that at the very least all HTTP traffic is filtered through the ubuntu server. This way, I can make the software cache data HTTP data.

Basically I have a bunch of computers that go in and out of here daily and they all download windows updates and a ton of other garbage over and over again. So, some kind of proxy software that can permanently cache data by mimetype or something is ideally what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: Squid is commonly used for this purpose.

More: http://askubuntu.com/questions/111487/what-updated-web-cache-servers-are-available-caching-http-proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't usually answer my own question but in this case, the best solution was to use the Apache Traffic Server. See more at http://trafficserver.apache.org/.